# Android Studio doesn't let me create an empty activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, installation, sdk

[that's the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THPXS.png)

Okay firstly I gotta tell you that I uninstalled Android Studio a few days ago due to some reasons. However, I reinstalled today and that's what I get. I cannot click on Next Button. I cannot create a new empty activity. I read that reinstalling SDKs works. So, I uninstalled and reinsatlled SDKs already. Nothing is working. How can I fix that?

I reinstalled SDKs but nothing happened.

Comment: Instead of clicking "empty activity", have you tried clicking "empty views activity"?

Comment: You can click on the finish button to create the project

Comment: but does it still work like that? will there be not anything missing?

Comment: empty views activity is just like "empty activity".  I tried it but nothing new or different

Comment: For UX, just click finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. It's just a (questionable) UI design choice to show a grayed out Next button instead of hiding the button when you get to the last page of the wizard. Just click Finish.